# Object identification in Opencv

Tags: opencv

When I take two images of the same object from different distances, they appear of different sizes. How can I compare and find out similar objects from both images using openCV?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible approaches:

Either you compare your images at different scales. For this you artificially decrease the size of one of your images and then compare your images just as you would if your objects had the same scale. You then take the best result from all the scales.

The other option is to use scale invariant features, where the scale of the object does not matter. [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) is a popular example for such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use SURF Features approach. SURF is much faster than SIFT.
Check [this](http://robocv.blogspot.it/2012/02/real-time-object-detection-in-opencv.html) out. To improve speed further, you can also use a Bag of Words approach, (always using SURF) check [this](http://webdiis.unizar.es/~dorian/index.php?p=32) out instead. You can also find a working example with DBoW2 library.